# Bot Framework startup and response time

Tags: botframework

I've just migrated my qnamaker bot to the new service and enabled the Facebook channel. I'm getting a fail from Facebook messenger admin because the response time is too slow. It take over a minute to fire up. I'm on S! standard, as it's the best available, located at Australia East. The Always On button is not available and the affinity cookie button disabled (Not available). What are my options?

Comment: "I'm on S1 standard" for the bot service, not for the App Service Plan of your Web App, right? In that case, can you check your App Service Plan: if you can't set "Always On" on your bot, you must be on a Free plan

Comment: Nicholas you've set me on the right path, I think it's the Consumption plan that's the problem

Comment: It's a function app bot?

Comment: Well I started from QnAMaker, it's all been created automagically. The migration from the Bot service/framework(?)  created the current function, which degraded the performance, I think.

Comment: This was based on a C# QnAMaker Template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted the bot and created a new bot using the node.js QnAMaker template. Hopefully this will resolve performance issues.